# Make Compass/Sass compile 2 .css, each with different configs

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I want compass to compile 2 different .css files:  1 with 
      `output_style = :nested` 
and one with 
        `output_style = :compressed`

So, filename_nested.css and filename_compressed.css, should be compiled.

I am just using a config.rb

Answer (score 1):

config.rb: This seems to work.  I wish i didnt have to spec the scss in  `Compass.compiler.compile('main.scss', 'main.min.css')` I would rather use the 'file' variable, but I have yet to work out how.  Also, I have yet to figure out how to get around this deprecated function.  [code found here](https://github.com/Subash/Prepros/issues/38#issuecomment-22006447)

```
http_path = "/wp-content/themes/Harmony_child/css/"
css_dir = ""
sass_dir = ""
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"
fonts_dir = "fonts"
cache_path = "C:/Temp/sasscache"

output_style = :nested
output_style = :compact
line_comments = true
color_output = false  

require 'fileutils'

on_stylesheet_saved do |file|
  if file.match('.min') == nil
    require 'compass'

    Compass.add_configuration(
        {
            :output_style => :compressed
        },
        'min' #ADDING A CONFIG REQUIRES A NAME
    )
    Compass.compiler.compile('main.scss', 'main.min.css')
    #Compass.compiler is deprecated. Use Compass.sass_compiler instead.
    #Compass.sass_compiler('main.scss', 'main.min.css')
    #yabbut, it dont work. the deprecated one does...

  end
end
```

Comment: It sounds like what you're really looking for is a way to create both developer friendly CSS (output_style = :nested) and production ready CSS (:output_style => :compressed). Rather than using Compass for this, have a look at Grunt (http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-awesome-build-script-grunt/) or Gulp (http://markgoodyear.com/2014/01/getting-started-with-gulp/)